# Docker run failed for MySQL container with permission errors when using a volume - Catalina MacOS X

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-for-mac

I am running the following command from the mac os x Catalina terminal:

```
docker run -p 13306:3306 --name mysqltest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="password12" --volume /usr/local/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:latest
```

I get the following error on the console screen:

> docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for run, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
> See 'docker run --help'.

This command runs and works if I run it without the --volume or -v option.

Also, if I run from the Docker dashboard with the volume option set I see the following error on the logs screen:

> 2022-04-12 19:44:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
> chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted**

This seems to indicate a permissions issue but I did add this path to the resources->file sharing in the docker dashboard.  I saw a few articles indicating an issue with the Catalina and Docker but did not find a fix for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, according to the documentation all attached volumes will be with `:rw` by default, after a few tests I could see in mac it is not that way, so add `:rw`  to the volume and it will work

```
docker run -p 13306:3306 --name mysqltest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="password12" --volume /usr/local/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql:rw -d mysql:latest
```

Also works with named volumes:

```
docker run -p 13306:3306 --name mysqltest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="password12" --volume mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:latest
```